# Counting number of files in a folder in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have these tables

```
Create table series (
    id_series Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name_series Varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    kcal Int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    type Varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    id_user Int NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (name_excercise),
    Primary Key (id_series)) ENGINE = MyISAM;

Create table excercise (
    id_excercise Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name_excercise Char(100) NOT NULL,
    date Date NOT NULL,
    start Time NOT NULL,
    end Time NOT NULL,
    km Double(10,2) NOT NULL,
    id_series Int NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (id_excercise),
   Primary Key (id_excercise)) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

They are basically like folders. Series has a name of a series and inside, there are subsequent excercises. What I need is to return every series user has and the number of the excercises inside. But I am having trouble with it, since I am not passing any ID of a concrete series in which it could count all the excercises. Is it possible to print that with only a user id?
I basically have this:

```
"SELECT * FROM series WHERE id_user = $id_user"
```

but need to combine it with this:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM excercise WHERE id_series = $id_series"
```

without the need of id_series.

Comment: you must use `JOIN` to join the tables by its primary key as foreign key at the other table

Comment: but "SELECT *, COUNT(*) as 'number' FROM series JOIN excercise ON(series.id_series = excercise.id_series) WHERE id_user = $id_user" returns only one row with the count of everything and "SELECT * FROM series JOIN excercise ON(series.id_series = excercise.id_series) WHERE id_user = $id_user" returns every excercise. I have a page with all series, lets say 3 different series:

Running, Cycling, Hiking.

There are 4 excercies in Running, 2 in Cycling and 8 in Hiking. And I need to access those number without clicking the series and passing the id via url or something

Comment: And oh.. You must be false-writing, it should be `EXERCISE` not `EXCERCISE`. But my answer depends on your example.

Comment: Is it possibly to get two or more duplicate series? What is your foreign key on excercise table? id_series or name_excercise?

Comment: Here you can see the whole DB. http://imgur.com/c6KCjs9
FK in my exercise table is the id. The name of the series must be unique. However the name of the exercise mustn't. Same like folders, you can have 3 folders, but each has to have their own unique name, but the files inside does not matter how they are named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query:

```
SELECT S.*, COUNT(E.id_excercise) AS NumOfExc
FROM series AS S
JOIN excercise AS E
   ON S.id_series = E.id_series
WHERE S.id_user = '$id_user'
GROUP BY E.id_series
UNION
SELECT *, 0 AS NumOfExc
FROM series
WHERE id_user = '$id_user'
AND id_series NOT IN (
    SELECT S.id_series AS id_series
    FROM series AS S
    JOIN excercise AS E
       ON S.id_series = E.id_series
    WHERE S.id_user = '$id_user'
    GROUP BY E.id_series
)
```

The above query will show what you need.

Comment: this works better then my attempts, but I still get only 1 row with the number of ALL exercises among all the series. So in my concrete scenario, I have 2 series. First has 14 entries and the second one has 1 entry. But with your select I get only information about the first series with the number of 15 exercises. (And yes, I have a typo there :) I was translating the words so you can udnerstand my table :))

Comment: But in my case the user has in DB 2 series, each with individual exercies, but it still returns just one row with the sum of all of his exercies across all series. And I need the id_user, so I can specify for which user I want to print those results. Only the logged user can see his own results.

Comment: You said '**each with individual exercies**'. So, you should put the `id_user` column in the `excercise` table not in the `series` table.

Comment: These are my tables: http://imgur.com/c6KCjs9. And this is my desired result: http://imgur.com/ZWqwHaL. But the only accessible number which I can use is the user_id. Sorry if I did not explain it good enough. But the id_user is a FK from the user table, it just have to be there and I cannot simply connect user table with the exercise table right?

Comment: Ok i got it. the name_exercise is not unique, right? I'll update the answer. :)

Comment: No it is not, only the name_series is :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66874/discussion-between-oki-erie-rinaldi-and-arcane).